# Numpy resize array with repeated values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose a vector whose items can take values from a finite set (`[7, 8, 9]` for example). I try to search the vector that meets some requirements.
I use numpy array to store possible states of a vector items. At first my vector is in indeterminate state that looks like that

```
>>> A = np.tile([7, 8, 9], (3, 1))
>>> A
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

---

My algorithm works (the details of algo are irrelevant here) by reducing the possible states for each cell. For example, if I want to claim that the first item can be only `9`, it works well, thanks to the [second broadcasting rule](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/quickstart.html#broadcasting-rules):

```
>>> A[0] = 9
>>> A
array([[9, 9, 9],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

However, if I want to claim that the item cannot be `8`, and try to assign `[7, 9]` to it:

```
>>> A[1] = [7, 9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3
```

What I want to achieve here is some kind of resizing that will automatically pad the value to desired length, e.g `[7, 9, 9]` or `[7, 9, 7]`. I do not care about the exact value, the only thing that matters is that `set(A[1]) == {7, 9}` after that operation.

Is it possible to do such a resize automatically with numpy?

Comment: I'm confused by the question... please check out [how to create a good **minimal** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get good responses.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense as a way to search for your desired vector.

Comment: What about a rule like "v[1] != v[2]"? Your algorithm would not work for something like this. You need something more like `[7,7,7],[7,7,8],[7,7,9],[7,8,7]...`.

Comment: @internet_user maybe my explanations are bad. I do not need the algorithm here. I just need a way to properly invalidate some 'bad' values, like '8' in my example, but I cannot simply assign [7, 9] as it requires array of size 3 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few low level operations that repeat array items as needed. They aren't commonly used.  `np.put` and `np.place` come to mind, but they work on a flattened array, and require boolean masking.  But `resize` might do the job here:

```
In [17]: np.resize([7,9],3)
Out[17]: array([7, 9, 7])
In [18]: A[1,:] = np.resize([7,9], A.shape[1])
In [19]: A
Out[19]: 
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [7, 9, 7],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

It even works for larger arrays:

```
In [20]: A[1,:] = np.resize([1,2,3,4], A.shape[1])
In [21]: A
Out[21]: 
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

I haven't used `resize` much, and don't know its limitations or quirks.

It's confusing to think of this action as 'broadcasting'.  It's stretching some very specific rules, which work for the program and users because they are unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have much experience with numpy, so I can misunderstood the concept of 'broadcasting'. Feel free to edit the question title